# Find $X_0$ s.t. the solution to $X'(t)={\begin{bmatrix}13&-8\\8&-7\end{bmatrix}}X(t), X(0)=X_0$ is in the first quadrant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Applying the Eigenvector method, we get

$$\begin{vmatrix} \lambda - 13 & 8 \\ -8 & \lambda +7\end{vmatrix} = 0 \iff \lambda = -3 \lor \lambda = 9$$

For these Eigenvalues we get $v_1 = (1,2), v_2 = (2,1)$ as Eigenvectors respectively. So the general solutions is of the form

$$X(t)= c_1 \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix} e^{-3t} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}e^{9t}$$

**But how can I find $X_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the solution to the initial value problem is contained  in the first quadrant?**

The exercise suggests that we draw the Phase Plane... Now, the Eigenvectors divide the plane along the lines $y=2x, y=x/2$. Should we require that $X_0$ is contained in the first quadrant between these lines? How can we justify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix $$\begin{vmatrix} \lambda - 13 & \lambda + 8 \\ -8 & \lambda +7\end{vmatrix} = 0 \iff \lambda = -3 \lor \lambda = 9$$

should have been $$\begin{vmatrix} \lambda - 13 &  8 \\ -8 & \lambda +7\end{vmatrix} = 0 \iff \lambda = -3 \lor \lambda = 9$$

$$X(t)= c_1 \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix} e^{-3t} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}e^{9t}$$ stays in the first quadrant if your coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$ are positive.

Comment: So $X_0 =(c_1 + 2c_2, 2c_1 + c_2)^T$ for any $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: yes, you are correct.